# Multiline PyParsing example

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to parse something really simple in PyParsing that is multiline but I'm struggling understand why it doesn't work. The string I want to parse is as follows.

```
string = '''START
    1   10; %   Name1
    2   20; %   Name2
END'''
```

I know that every line between the START and END tokens will contain one or more positive / negative numbers that can be `int` or `float` types. I also expect that a user may optionally add additional meta data after an `%` sign.

So I start by defining the basic grammar for Floats and Names.

```
Float = Word(nums + '.' + '-')
Name = Word(alphanums)
```

I know that a line can contain one or more `Float` followed by a semi-colon, and optionally by a `% Name`.

```
Line = OneOrMore(Float)('data') + Suppress(Literal(';')) + Suppress(Optional(Literal('%'))) + Optional(OneOrMore(Name)('name')) + Suppress(LineEnd())
```

I expect many lines, so I can define the grammar for Lines as follows.

```
Lines = OneOrMore(Group(Line))
```

I use `Group` as suggested by Paul in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40667527/how-to-retrieve-list-of-values-from-result-object-in-pyparsing) to make retrieving possible.

```
grammar = Suppress(Keyword('START')) + Lines + Suppress(Keyword('END'))

grammar.parseString(string)
```

However this throws an error that says the following

```
ParseException: Expected end of line (at char 62), (line:3, col:19)
```

Full code below for easier copy and pasting.

```
string = '''START
    1   10; %   Name1
    2   20; %   Name2
END'''

from pyparsing import Word, Keyword, nums, OneOrMore, Optional, Suppress, Literal, alphanums, LineEnd, LineStart, Group

Float = Word(nums + '.' + '-')
Name = Word(alphanums)
Line = OneOrMore(Float)('data') + Suppress(Literal(';')) + Suppress(Optional(Literal('%'))) + Optional(OneOrMore(Name)('name')) + Suppress(LineEnd())
Lines = OneOrMore(Group(Line))

grammar = Suppress(Keyword('START')) + Lines + Suppress(Keyword('END'))
grammar.parseString(string)
```

Edit :

I've tried the following to no avail either.

```
string = '''START
    1   10; %   Name1
    2   20; %   Name2
END'''

from pyparsing import Word, Keyword, nums, OneOrMore, Optional, Suppress, Literal, alphanums, LineEnd, LineStart, Group

Float = Word(nums + '.' + '-')
Name = Word(alphanums)
NL = Suppress(LineEnd())
Line = OneOrMore(Float)('data') + Suppress(Literal(';')) + Optional(~NL +
                                                            Suppress(Literal('%'))
                                                            + OneOrMore(Name)('name') + NL ) | NL
Lines = OneOrMore(Group(Line))

grammar = Suppress(Keyword('START')) + Lines + Suppress(Keyword('END'))
grammar.parseString(string)
```

The only thing that does seem to work is if I use restOfLine

```
Line = OneOrMore(Float)('data') + Suppress(Literal(';')) + Optional(restOfLine)
```

However, this does not return the portion after the semi-colon in a structured fashion and I have to parse it separately again. Is that the recommended approach?

Comment: Add "Name.setDebug()"and "Float.setDebug()" and see if that output is helpful.

Comment: That output seems to suggest that `OneOrMore(Name)` is going further than the end of the line. What is the recommended way to make sure that OneOrMore(Name) stops at the end of the line. I tried OneOrMore(Name) + NL and that didn't work either, and I wasn't able to understand why.

Comment: First of all, is "2" a valid Name?  Second, are end-of-lines significant in your grammar? If so, then you should remove them from the set of ignorable whitespace, using ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars (see example inline with docs at https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.ParserElement-class.html#setDefaultWhitespaceChars). Finally, you might want to tighten up your definitions of Float and Name. As you have them now, Float will match strings such as "...", "---", and "1.1.1", and Name will match "12345" and "221B".

Comment: Thanks Paul! That solved it. I had to remove newline from the Parser element. I've posted the full answer below for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing new lines from the default whitespace characters is what was needed to solve this. As Paul suggested in his comment, other improvements can be made to ensure that it parses floats and names more strictly.

```
string = '''START
    1   10; %   Name1
    2   20; %   Name2
END'''

from pyparsing import Word, Keyword, nums, OneOrMore, Optional, Suppress, Literal, alphanums, LineEnd, LineStart, Group, ParserElement

ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars(" \t")

Float = Word(nums + '.' + '-')
Name = Word(alphanums)
NL = Suppress(LineEnd())
Line = OneOrMore(Float)('data') + Suppress(Literal(';')) + Optional(~NL +
                                                            Suppress(Literal('%'))
                                                            + OneOrMore(Name)('name') + NL ) | NL
Lines = OneOrMore(Group(Line))

grammar = Suppress(Keyword('START')) + Lines + Suppress(Keyword('END'))
grammar.parseString(string)
```